# How to make a connection string class?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbconnection

I have developed an application, based on 7 winform. My database is on MS Access. I want to create one common single class for connection string, and to use it in all winforms. So that, i can avoid copying and pasting connection string in all forms. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You don't need a new class - you can pull the string from app.config in each form. [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have your connection string in App.Config file

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDBConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDB; Integrated Security=true" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

And then you can access it like:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

See: [How to: Add an Application Configuration File to a C# Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)

Comment: i have created in APP.CONFIG and did what you told me to do. but i am having problem in accessing it. i mean "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnection"].ConnectionString;"   this whole line should be in blue color but it is still in black. it means my application could not read this line

Comment: @Dany, right click on project references and  add reference to System.Configuration.

Comment: ok wait. i am trying this. one more thing, my database is OLEDB so what changes should i have to make in these codes?

Comment: @Dany, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db/

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a class and a static member like @scottk, but I'll wrap a check for the `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol so I can switch to a development database on debug builds.  I also use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` for readability, even though it really is overkill:

```
public static class ConnectionStrings
{
    #if DEBUG
    public static string DBName
    {
        get
        {
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = @"C:\devDB.mdb",
                Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0"
            };

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
    #else
    public static string DBName
    {
        get
        {
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = @"C:\prodDB.mdb",
                Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0"
            };

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Good idea to check for debug mode. Sometimes it is necessary to debug using the production table, or their may be multiple test databases though. So, giving the user a choice of which database to use if in debug mode would be good (such as at log on screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class with a static member and property.

```
public class Utils
{
    private static string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDB; Integrated Security=true";

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            connectionString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access it like:

```
string connString = Utils.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: its giving me an error in private static connectionString = ""; it says Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: @Dany I forgot "string" in that line, sorry. Updated the code a bit.